# SQLite - no errors, however, no data uploaded to DB

Tags: java, sqlite, codenameone

I have developed a mobile application using the CodeName One plugin for Java in the Netbeans IDE.

CodeName One uses the Database API. https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/db/Database.html

I'm running some tests (there are around 10 values I would like to upload, however, just testing the connection ect by uploading ID, Fname and Lname values.

```
Database db = null;
        Cursor cur = null;
        String Fname = findTxtFirstn(c).getText();
        String Lname = findTxtLastn(c).getText();

        try{

            Database ARdb = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("RecordsDB.db");            
            System.out.println("Connection secured to database.");

            ARdb.beginTransaction();

            String createTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RecordsTable ("
                    + "ID integer PRIMARY KEY,"
                    + "First_Name text NOT NULL,"
                    + "Last_Name text NOT NULL)";

            String query = "insert into RecordsTable (ID,First_Name,Last_Name) values (3,'Test','Testerton')";       

            ARdb.execute(createTable);
            ARdb.execute(query);

            ARdb.commitTransaction();  

        } catch(Exception e){

            System.out.println("Error! Connection Failed to DB" +e.getMessage());

        } finally {

            Util.cleanup (db);
            Util.cleanup(cur);

        }
```

I get no errors and everything runs, however, the values are not in the database when I check it. Am I missing something here? I have followed tutorials and looked over the Codename One API. I can't find the solution.

Edit: I need to change the value of the primary number each run (else I get an error: number needs to be unique), This tells me the values are being stored on the database, unfortunately, when I check the database in question there are no records on it, so where it the data going?

I used DB Browser for SQLite.

Comment: Suggestion: write one separate method to insert the data after creating the table.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried performing your modifying change in a transaction? In databases with transactions all modifying operations (CREATE, INSERT, ...) need to be performed in a transaction.

```
ARdb.beginTransaction();
// your create code 
ARdb.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have changed the code, however, I got and error saying the primary key needs to be unique - I then changed the value to 1 and it ran through with no errors (like before anyway). so a table has been created, but it's not being uploaded to the database. What is going on?

Comment: Ok, so the database is created, but the data is not inserted? Basically the first error (primary key needs to be unique) would let me assume that there was already one entry with the ID 2 in the database

Comment: Basically it is important, that a primary key (in your case this is the ID column) must be unique. If you try insert another row in the table with the same primary key, the database will not let you do this, giving you the not unique primary key error. If the table is created, but no data is inserted, then my next guess would be, that the table and data insertion needs to be done in separate transactions. I don't use sqlite regularly, so I'm not that sure in that point.

Comment: I updated my question - that should be clearer. Thanks for helping me btw

Comment: Just for the record: Are you absolutely sure, that there is nothing in the database? How do you check for the existence? Because normally (from what I know with other databases) the non unique error only appears if a row with the desired ID already exists (exist means inserted and transaction commit). And you're welcome.

Comment: I used DB Browser for SQLite. I checked for records and only  one record exists that I entered using the browser. This also means that ID:1 was taken, however, the program still accepted that primary key. According to the program 1,2,3 are now occupied, however, I was able to make 2 and 3 records in the browser. I have no idea where this data is going because it's not in the specified database.

Comment: Maybe you access two different databases by mistake? What are the connection data you are using in the DB Browser? Because maybe the URLs are wrong. 
The database you create is most probably somewhere in your code folder (e.g. target or build or whatever way you use to build and run the code) and maybe in the DB Browser you access a different path?

Comment: @JSint you could use a static path for testing purposes for the database created in your code. e.g.
     Database ARdb = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("C:\Users\Username\Desktop\RecordsDB.db");
or if you use linux
    Database ARdb = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("/home/username/RecordsDB.db");

and access this database also by the DB browser.

Comment: Don't use full paths for `openOrCreate` only db names. C: doesn't exist on a mobile phone ;-) You can add the word `AUTOINCREMENT` after `PRIMARY KEY` in the create statement which will automatically insert a unique primary key for you

Comment: It won't let me specify the path. Keeps saying illegal expression. I just edited the db name with the full path. This is very strange. Maybe I will try different DB software. Any suggestions?

Comment: By "it" you mean the DB Browser? My personal favourite for database interaction is [SQuirreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) but there you also need the drivers for HSQLDB. 
But before that: it would be easier to extend your test program, so that you first add data in the database and then use the same database object to query data from the database (but outside the transaction). Then you know if the data is saved or not. I still think that the problem here is, that the database api writes in a different database file than the one you check with the DB browser.

Comment: You aren't allowed to specify the path as I explicitly said. Databsse's are stored in a device native directory and should include JUST the filename. In order to supply a downloadable database please check out the SQL section in the developer guide https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html#_sql