# SQLite - Select text and get value to Textfield in Codename One for Java

Tags: java, sqlite, codenameone

I raised a question regarding the mobile applications data being stored in a database, however, not the database I specified:

[SQLite - no errors, however, no data uploaded to DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49239038/sqlite-no-errors-however-no-data-uploaded-to-db)

I have created another GUI element to search the database for specific information for testing purposes.

CodeName One uses the Database API. https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/db/Database.html

Unfortunately, there are plenty of great examples online, however, not with regards to CodeName One.

```
Database db = null;
Cursor cur = null;

        try{

            Database ARdb = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("RecordsDB.db"); 

            System.out.println("Connection secured to database.");

            ARdb.beginTransaction();

            String SelectRecords = "SELECT Last_Name, Phone, Email, Postcode 
            FROM TestRecord";

            cur = ARdb.executeQuery(SelectRecords);

            //This is where I'm trying to set the text of col Last_Name
            findTxtLastnSearch(c).setText(cur.getText("Last_Name"));

            ARdb.commitTransaction(); 

        } catch(Exception e){

            System.out.println("Error! Connection Failed to DB" 
            +e.getMessage());

        } finally {

            Util.cleanup (db);
            Util.cleanup(cur);

        }
    }
```

I have selected the records for testing. I would like to now upload the results to textfields, however, I can't figure out how to do it. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get back from your executed query is not a single row but a cursor that contains multiple rows so you need to loop over it and handle each row.

Look at the example in your second link. Something like this

```
int indexForLastName = cur.getColumnIndex("Last_Name");
while(cur.next()) {
  Row row = cur.getRow()
  String lastname = row.getString(indexForLastName);
  //more stuff
}
```

Comment: with the line: String lastname = row.getString("Last_Name"); - I get cannot convert to int? Thanks for your help btw,

Comment: Yeah, getString takes an int not a string, my mistake. Just use that instead.

Comment: Honestly, that is the error I keep getting using that code. I will try a couple of other things.

Comment: I guess one way would be to get the index from the cursor method getColumnIndex. I updated my answer to use this

Comment: String lastname = "Last_Name";
               
               String lastnameVal = lastname.valueOf(row);
               
               System.out.println(lastnameVal);

Comment: output: com.codename1.impl.javase.SECursor@10c28f00

Comment: A row is of type Row and contains multiple values, corresponding to what columns you included in your SQL query, that you need to retrieve separately. See the documentation for Cursor and Row in the documentation you linked to, https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/db/Database.html and my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, with this solution I am able to verify that a database was created with the specifications. This is a relief! The only issue is that it will only show me the last record, so I need to figure out how to navigate between records next.

Comment: It will go over each record since that's loop code. Place a breakpoint in the debugger and see that next will move you to the next row.

Comment: My first idea was to put break; at the end of the loop, however, The record just remained as the first record. Methods like "gotofirst" ect do not work with this API. Do you know where I can find the functions list that works with Codename One?

Comment: In the second link in your question select “Frames” at the top then in the left column a bit down under “All Classes” you find links to the documentation for Cursor and Row

Comment: Thank you Joakim. That is exactly what I will need to finish my testing table viewer.